# How to use PayPal for payments on my website if there's no SDK for my server-side language?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I have a website written in a language for which there's no PayPal SDK. I want to accept payments via PayPal on it.

1) How can I do that?

2) There's so much documentation there so that I'm at loss: **where** and **for what** should I look for? Is it PayPal checkout? Or PayPal REST API? Or something else?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: If you’re proficient in a supported language, you can always port(translate) another SDK.